# How to compile older version of mosquitto source code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I need older version of **mosquitto** that supports tlsv1.
When I try to `make` any of older versions [for example 1.0.1] on Debian 11, I get this error:

```
cc -Wall -ggdb -O2 -I. -I.. -I../lib -DVERSION="\"1.0.1\"" -DTIMESTAMP="\"2023-03-14 12:46:16+0100\"" -DWITH_BROKER -DWITH_TLS -DWITH_TLS_PSK -DWITH_BRIDGE -DWITH_PERSISTENCE -DWITH_MEMORY_TRACKING -c read_handle_server.c -o read_handle_server.o
read_handle_server.c: In function ‘mqtt3_handle_connect’:
read_handle_server.c:233:4: warning: ‘ASN1_STRING_data’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  233 |    context->username = _mosquitto_strdup((char *)ASN1_STRING_data(name_entry->value));
      |    ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:15,
                 from ../lib/mosquitto_internal.h:40,
                 from ./mosquitto_broker.h:35,
                 from read_handle_server.c:35:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:554:1: note: declared here
  554 | DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(unsigned char *ASN1_STRING_data(ASN1_STRING *x))
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
read_handle_server.c:233:77: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘X509_NAME_ENTRY’ {aka ‘struct X509_name_entry_st’}
  233 |    context->username = _mosquitto_strdup((char *)ASN1_STRING_data(name_entry->value));
      |                                                                             ^~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:54: read_handle_server.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/mosquitto_20230309/mosquitto-1.0.1/src'
make: *** [Makefile:17: mosquitto] Error 2
```

I'm totally lame at C so I as need simple answer as possible.

Comment: It looks like your older `mosquito` needs an older OpenSSL.  This is a rabbit hole that you, being self-declared "totally lame at C", are probably not equipped to get to the bottom of.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You may be right, but isn't the purpose of this website existance that people like me could ask people like you for help and do my best to try "to get to the bottom"? Could you point me to how to get older OpenSSL and how to decide which version of it I need?

Comment: I would not put it in those terms myself.  Instead, I'd say that providing certain kinds of help related to questions about programming is one of the primary modes of operation of this site.  However, finding or installing software are not among the kinds of help we normally provide; they are off topic here.